# DialogFragment dismissed when home is pressed

Tags: android, android-support-library

In my application I'm showing a `DialogFragment` (compatibility library) containing a `ProgressBar` that gets updated and executes some code.
When the user changes the activity (Home or back button, some element clicked in the UI) the background `Thread`s keep being executed, but the DialogFragment is dismissed. Is it possible to get it back when the `Activity` is resumed?

I don't want a new one, I want to show the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself. Override your `FragmentActivity` `onResume` method this way:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```